# Can I use an IDE other than Visual Studio to develop a Windows GPIO Driver?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, driver

My company is interested in developing a GPIO Driver for Windows to use with proprietary peripherals and would like to save money by using an IDE other than Visual Studio.

After researching on Google, the MSDN, and StackOverflow, I was unable to determine if I am able to develop a Windows GPIO Driver using an IDE other than Visual Studio. The MSDN only gives tips on how to develop a Windows GPIO driver using Visual Studio and the StackOverflow questions pertain to specific development issues, while Google gave me a combination of the two. None of the methods gave me any kind of concrete or even ballpark answer, so I decided to post my first StackOverflow question.

If it is useful, I am using Windows 10 but I have access to, and can develop on, a Windows 7 system as well.

So the first question would be: Can I use an IDE other than Visual Studio to develop a Windows GPIO Driver and if so, what would I need from VS to do so?

Can I use an (open source/free) IDE other than Visual Studio, considering I am developing on Windows?

If I have to use Visual Studio, what is the reason that another IDE would not work (i.e. missing tools, missing libraries, poor Microsoft design decision, etc)?

Comment: What about Eclipse CDT, Qt-Creator, Code Blocks and all the plethora of IDE's out there? The question is which underlying toolchain you use. And yes, MinGw would serve you well on windows.

Comment: You can use ANY text editor.  You could use Notepad if you wanted.  The whole point of an IDE is to help tie things together for you.  So if you want to avoid using VS, you just need to learn all about how VS does what it does.

Comment: _@Jake_ I've been trying to keep my answer as neutral and recommendation free as possible. Though you should note, that questions that actually ask for recommendation of a specific tool or 3rd party resource are [off-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: And I get that. I must have misread the rules and apologize. The main question was if I was forced to use VS so I thought it was okay, as a follow up question, to ask for recommendations if I received a certain answer. I'll edit it quick and watch out for this in the future. Much appreciated.

Comment: @JakeSamz Banged everything in shape a bit and retracted my close vote.

Comment: Unfortunately using a solution based on a non-Microsoft compilers isn't going to be as easy the comments and answers makes out. In particular any solution based on MinGW (GCC) isn't going to be a drop in replacement. Microsoft's headers don't work with GCC. The only reason why you can compile Windows applications with it is because MinGW comes with its own version of most of the Windows SDK headers. MinGW's support for the Windows DDK headers is much more limited.

Comment: I should also add that Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition is free for commercial use if your company is small enough. It can be used by up to 5 users at the same company if the company isn't too big (>250 PCs or >$1 Million US Dollars in annual revenue),

Comment: @RossRidge Do you have experience using MinGW/GCC with the Windows DDK? Just curious how much of a headache it would be to use MinGW with the DDK considering configuration speed is something we take into account. If we would be spending days/weeks messing with configuration settings, I think we would rather drop the money on VS because of the development support.

Comment: I've never tried to use GCC with the Windows DDK, but if any thing like tying to use GCC with the Windows SDK then it will be days/weeks of work to get the Windows DDK headers to compile without errors. Configuration settings shouldn't take too long to figure out, it's mainly that you need some different linker settings and there seems to be a few examples on the Web.

Comment: The Visual Studio IDE has nothing to do with Microsoft's C++ compiler. As I read it, the question is *specifically* about IDEs, and makes no mention of a desire to use a different compiler, such as GCC. @ross I'm pretty sure that the WDK/DDK is a free download, and includes Microsoft's compiler. It certainly used to be.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't see why you've addressed me in your comment, but if you're trying to help the original poster you should make it more clear that you're suggesting he can a get free copy of Microsoft's compiler and use it in combination with some IDE other than Visual Studio.

Comment: I got the WDK/DDK for free. @RossRidge You were certainly correct: VS was super easy to develop Windows drivers on, and it also allowed me to use built-in driver tools to deploy and test on my VM. Cheers gents!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So the first question would be: Can I use an IDE other than Visual Studio to develop a Windows GPIO Driver and if so, what would I need from VS to do so?

Yes, you can.

There's no officially *recommended* or *best* IDE to choose. Just get one that fit's your comforts regarding

- syntax highlighting
- debugging support
- toolchain support
- intellisense support when typing code
- etc. frills and gadgets ...

The question merely is, if you are required to use the MSVC compiler to develop any artifacts (executables, shared libraries) for a windows target.

And the answer fortunately is: **No.**

There are alternative free toolchains like MinGw GCC or Clang available, and you can use any IDE that supports to choose support for that toolchain.

You can even use a simple text editor like Notepad++.

> Can I use an (open source/free) IDE other than Visual Studio, considering I am developing on Windows?

You can do anything you need using the free tools available.

But take care about correct licensing (regarding standard library implementations etc.), supposed you're developing commercial product.

Comment: Thank you so much! For clarification, would toolchain have been a better choice of words for me to use than IDE in this case?

Comment: @JakeSamz _"would toolchain have been a better choice of words"_ Probably yes. Because the _toolchain_ is the essential thing needed to compile code for a particular target machine environment. You can even use cross-toolchains on a linux environment to compile code for a windows target (again MinGw supports that for example).

Comment: That is very good to know considering I have used cross-toolchains (GCC for building coreboot with Tianocore payloads). So when MSDN/other sources talk about creating a UMDF or KMDF project for a Windows Driver in VS, what does that mean in regards to other IDEs/Toolchains?

Comment: @JakeSamz I didn't check that deeply, but my probably best research came up with [this](https://myworks2012.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/how-to-compile-windows-x64-driver-using-mingw-w64-gcc/). But that's a different question deviating from your original one too far now. And sorry, I'm not an expert regarding windows driver development.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use any toolchain you want to develop drivers for Windows.  You can use any editor and compiler.

You need to *focus* on the requirements of a Windows driver.  Microsoft is always going to recommend you use their products.  For example, they may suggest using C# with Visual Studio.  Microsoft may make driver development easier by using their tools (more money for them).

The final "executable" driver leaves no clues as to the language or toolchain used to create it.

The are other resources available for information about Windows Drivers than MSDN.

Comment: I know there are other resources available than the MSDN on Windows Drivers. I also said I Googled and searched this site for related information. Regardless, this was very helpful. Do you know of any good reference materials on this?

Comment: _"they may suggest using C# with Visual Studio"_ [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) is great to overcome this.

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to suggest writing drivers in C#. I mean, I guess you could write certain drivers in managed code, like audio drivers, which I believe run in user-mode now. But there will be no writing kernel-mode software in C#, and even if you found a way to overcome the technical limitations, I would strongly encourage you not to try and do so, for the sake of your users.

Comment: Also, this statement that the final executable leaves no clues as to the language or toolchain used to create it is certainly wrong. Aside from the fact that compilers, and especially optimizers, have characteristic signatures in how they compile certain pieces of code, information about the toolchain, linked libraries, and etc. are generally included in the metadata unless you take specific care to strip them out. (Not that any of this disagrees with the larger point that it *doesn't matter* which compiler/toolchain you use.)

Comment: @CodyGray, so you are saying that the executable from compiled BASIC, FORTRAN, C, and Compiled LISP have features that tell which toolchain they were produced from.  For example, I can use GNU Fortran and GNU C command line to create executables and from these executables on can determine which IDE I used (eg. Eclipse, Code Blocks, none, etc).